# How to know when all tasks are completed after HTTPRequest (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, asynchronous, httprequest

I am currently facing an issue that has been bothering me for days. I have tried several solutions but don't seem to be able to fix the issue. Let me illustrate what is going on.

I have a feed with posts in a `UITableView`. As soon as the user selects one of the cells, he is shown a detailed view of this post in a new `UIViewController`. In there, I set up all views and call a function `loadPostDetails()` in the `viewDidLoad()` method. As soon as the view shows up, a custom loading indicator is presented which is set to disappear (hide) when the details are loaded and then the `UITableView` of this `UIViewController` (let's call it `PostController`) is shown.

In my `loadPostDetails()`function, I make a HTTPRequest which acquires the JSON data I need. This returns three kinds of info: the post details themselves, the likes and the comments. I need to handle each of these three elements before I reload the `UITableView` and show it. Currently, I do it like this:

```
HTTP.retrievePostDetails(postID: postID, authRequired: true) { (error, postDetails) in

    if(error != nil) {

        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

    } else {

        if let postDetails = postDetails, let postInfo = postDetails["postInfoRows"] as? [[String: Any]], let postLikesCount = postDetails["postLikesCount"] as? Int, let postLikesRows = postDetails["postLikesRows"] as? [[String: Any]], let postCommentsRows = postDetails["postCommentsRows"] as? [[String: Any]] {

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                let tableFooterView = self.postTableView.tableFooterView as! tableFooterView

                if let postTitle = postInfo[0]["postTitle"] as? String, let postText = postInfo[0]["postText"] as? String {

                    self.postTitleLabel.text = postTitle
                    self.postTextLabel.text = postText

                }

                for (index, postCommentRow) in postCommentsRows.enumerated() {

                    tableFooterView.postComments.append(Comment(userID: postCommentRow["userID"] as! Int, userProfilePicURL: postCommentRow["userProfilePicURL"] as! String, userDisplayName: postCommentRow["userDisplayName"] as! String, commentTimeStamp: postCommentRow["commentTimeStamp"] as! TimeInterval, commentText: postCommentRow["commentText"] as! String))

                }

                var likeDisplayNames = [String]()

                for postLikeRow in postLikesRows {

                    likeDisplayNames.insert(postLikeRow["userDisplayName"] as! String, at: 0)

                }

                if(postLikesCount > 2) {

                    tableFooterView.likesLabel.text = "\(likeDisplayNames[0]), \(likeDisplayNames[1]) and \(postLikesCount - 2) others"

                } else {

                    tableFooterView.likesLabel.text = "\(postLikesCount) likes"

                }

            }

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {

                self.screenDotsLoader.isHidden = true
                self.screenDotsLoader.stopAnimating()
                self.postTableView.isHidden = false
                self.postTableView.reloadData()

            })

        }

    }

 }
```

*Note: I add more text to `UILabels`, like the date and the profile picture of the user, but I have removed a couple of lines to make it more readible and because the extra code is irrelevant for this problem.*

Now, as you might already see, I call the reload stuff 1 second later, so in 95% of the cases it works just fine (but still, it is not perfect, as it is a "hack"). In the other 5%, the layout can't figure out the right constraints, resulting in a very bad layout.

I have in the last days tried to play with `DispatchGroups()`, but I couldn't figure out how to do it. I am in fact trying to know when all tasks have been performed, so when all `UILabels` have been updated, all `UIImageViews` have been updated etc. Only then, I want to reload the `UITableView`.

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction so I can enhance my user experience a bit more. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DispatchGroups` is used when you do a bunch of asynchronous tasks together , and need to be notified upon finish of all , but currently you don't do this as when you receive the response , all are inside the main thread which is synchronous ( serial ) which means all the stuff before reloading the table will happen before it's reload , so you're free to use dispatch after if this will make sense to your UX

Comment: You were right. I was looking in the wrong place as my issue had nothing to do with async requests. I am using a tableFooterView and a tableHeaderView, and I needed to implement a function to recalculate the size of both. Did this, created the function using systemLayoutSizeFitting on those table & header views, and called it inside the main.async call without the 1 sec delay. Initial tests show this works as expected, will test a bit more but I feel confident. Thanks for putting me on the right track!